# spectral subtraction for stationary noise

Tags: audio, noise, denoising

my recording was suffering from stationary background noise. I used spectral subtraction to remove it. the noise is reduced in loudness but not eliminated completely.
before:
http://vocaroo.com/i/s18FtoUwSah4
after:
http://vocaroo.com/i/s12U4feLs6iu

is spectral subtraction working?What can I do to further improve my results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In almost all practical applications of spectral subtraction it's unrealistic to expect that the noise can be completely eliminated. Even if this were possible, the price to be paid would be severe distortion of the desired signal.

What you can try is tweak the parameters. The most obvious parameter to tune is the (over)-subtraction factor, which determines how much of the estimated noise is subtracted from the noisy spectrum. It is not uncommon to have over-subtraction factors of around $2.0$ or $2.5$. Of course you have to make sure that the resulting estimated speech (magnitude or power) spectrum remains non-negative.